# Not able to select "Planning Entity Collection" in OptaPlanner Quickstart

Tags: jbpm, optaplanner, drools-kie-server

I Need learn the Optaplanner. And new to these, Wildfly and jBPM and all

I have just followed the instructions from the [link](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.28.0.Final/optaplanner-wb-es-docs/html_single/#_planner.quickstart), to learn OptaPlanner Workbench and Execution server.

OptaPlanner Version: 7.28.0.Final
OS : Linux
WildFly Version : wildfly-14.0.0.Final

I have created Assets, now when I am configuring the Planner as in [section 2.1.4.1](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.28.0.Final/optaplanner-wb-es-docs/html_single/#_planner_configuration)

I have done the Planner config for ComputerList as below
[image]

but for ProcessList the **"Planning Entity Collection"** not able to find it shows **Planning Value Range Provider** where i am doing the mistake

[image]

Comment: Have you tried downloading and using the optaplanner zip (the big green button on optaplanner.org)?

Comment: Got your point.. i have to read and go though the examples. the doc may not up to data..